# Search for string then print the next line from text file

Tags: java

**Update: I figured it out. See below.**

I'm trying to find a specific string in a text document. Once I find the string the only thing I want to print is the information in the lines following it until there is a blank line. I've been able to find the string and print, but I'm always printing the line that contains the string first.

Example:

I search for Ted in this doc:

```
blah blah
ted
blah blah
blah
bl

mike
```

Now I print: `ted blah blah blah bl`
I want: `blah blah blah bl`

I thought maybe `nextline()` but I honestly have no idea how to use scanner since we are using textIO instead in my class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean output=false; 
    String name=""; 
    String junk="CHAMBERS";
    TextIO.putln("Search name:");
    name = TextIO.getln();      
    TextIO.readFile("doc.txt"); 
    name = name.toUpperCase();
    TextIO.putln(name + "'s "+"Info");

    output = false; 
    while (false == TextIO.eof()) {
        String line = TextIO.getln(); 
        if (line.isEmpty())
            output = false; 
        if (line.indexOf(name) >= 0 && line.indexOf(junk)<=0){
            output = true; 
        }       
        if (output){
          line=line.trim();
          TextIO.putln(name+":"+'"'+line+'"');}
    }

    TextIO.putln();

}
```

Since I can't answer my own question I'll put this here:

In the If(output) tree:

```
if (output){
line=line.trim();
if (line.startsWith(name)){}
else{
TextIO.putln('"'+line+'"');}}
```

This checks the line for the string 'name' then ignores it. Then it goes on to the next line. I had to use trim() in case some lines had spaces before the name. This is the only way I found, as a newbie, to avoid constantly creating new lines for each time it finds 'name'. I removed some formatting that was required to make this a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 1):

The function your using to find the String "ted" must be giving you the position of the first character of the string ted. Try to add to that position the length of the String ted and then write the rest of the line (from that index to the end of the line).

Comment: This isn't totally clear to me but I think I may have an idea on what you're saying. The problem is, and I suppose I could edit my post again to shot it, that 'ted' may show up 20 times in the document. So I want to ignore the line that contains that string entirely. I think what you're saying may cause me to have a lot of blank lines that I want to avoid. For a while I thought maybe using   .substring()  but I can't get it to only effect the name line.

Comment: For each line You get the position of the last occurence of the String ted then You add the size of the String ted get the substring of that line from the position with the added lenght to the end of the line and then print it

Comment: If You have: ted blá ted blá blá ted aaaaa You print: aaaaa

Comment: Note that the function indexof gires You the position of the first character of the first occurence of the String ted in the line

Comment: Yes, but I'm printing several lines and 'ted' wont be in front of all of them. I only see the name one time before the end of all his information. Then ted may show up 5 more names down and I have to do it all over again. It's like the script for a show. I need to print out 'ted' lines throughout this document.